# Testing the existence of single instance -Singleton-C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, singleton

How to write test in Nunit to test that only one instance is created by my singleton class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var first = MySingleton.Instance;
var second = MySingleton.Instance;
Assert.AreSame(first, second);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the object twice and use Assert to make sure they have the same reference